# How do I solve the following dilemma that it seems that i've run into?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-cast, diamond-problem

I've got this problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
protected:
    int a = 0;
};

class B : public virtual A{
};

class C : public virtual A{
};

class D : public B, public C{
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, D & d);
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, D & d){
    in >> d.B::a;
    in >> d.C::a;
    std::cout<<d.B::a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<d.C::a<<std::endl;

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    D d;
    std::cin>>d;
}
```

Example input:

```
10 21
```

Output:

```
21 21
```

Expected output:

```
10 21
```

Can anyone help? I'm guessing it has something to do with dynamic / static cast but I don't know very much about those.

Comment: What is the dilemma?

Comment: I've mentioned in main as a comment
INPUT:     10 21 (example)
OUTPUT:    21 21
EXPECTED OUTPUT: 10 21

Comment: `B` and `C` inherit virtually from `A`, meaning that `d.B::a` and `d.C::a` actually refer to the same underlying `A::a`. You essentially are writing to the same variable twice, then reading from it twice, and therefore you only get the most recent value written to it. Drop the `virtual` from the inheritance.

Comment: In my main code the problem was actually something else, but nevertheless I've fixed it cause you helped me. Thanks !

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ diamond multiple inheritance"

Comment: The only sane way I know of to use multiple inheritance is to limit classes to having at most one state-having "body" parent class, plus zero or more stateless "interface" parent classes (a la `interface` in Java). As soon as you allow state in multiple parent classes, your code becomes very brittle: Correctness of code in derived classes depends on the complete inheritance hierarchy of their parents.